# pd.DataFrame sees my rows as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate a DataFrame that has normally distributed data. However, when I try to make a DataFrame out of the data I generated, Python takes my data as columns rather than rows.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mh_m = 178
sh_m = 10
size = 10000
h_m = np.random.normal(loc=mh_m,scale=sh_m,size=(size))
pd.DataFrame([h_m])
```

I get a dataframe with a 1000 columns rather than one with 1000 rows. Does anyone know how to make this work. Thank you very much!

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(h_m)` ?

Comment: you can also use `df.T` method to invert columns and rows.